# Selenium 4. find_element_by_css_selector not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Based on the [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_element_by_css_selector#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector) the *find element by css selector* syntax is `element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')` but the example shows there is `a.nav` before the `#` sign ‘(**a.nav**#home)’ which based on [this website](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/css-selectors-in-selenium) is HTML tag.

In another part of the [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/_print/#pg-56b8b595648aa8ba6a92086f0ee2be07) the `css_selector` even doesn't have the `#` sign: `ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1')`

---

Questions:

1. Which syntax is correct? with or without the HTML tag? with or without the `#` sign?
2. In Visual Studio Code I used these syntaxes to find the search boxes or sign-in boxes. It worked in [this website](https://www.yatra.com/) but didn't work in [this website](https://www.arizonarealestate.com/). Could you help me find the search box using `css_selector` in [this website](https://www.arizonarealestate.com/)?

Here is an example of my scripts:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.arizonarealestate.com")

    searchBox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#input[placeholder='Enter city, address, neighborhood, zip, or MLS #']")
    searchBox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#input[placeholder='Enter city, address, neighborhood, zip, or MLS #']")
    searchBox.send_keys("Some text")

    searchBtn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block.js-qs-btn").click()
finally:
        #print("============ Done!")
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking a css selector is just a string with some specific syntax and is not really defined by the selenium WebDriver itself.

You should have a look at the MDN description of [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

In your question you specifically seem to have question on where to specify the [id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) specified with the `#` character. This selector should actually only be used just by itself as all id's in a page should be unique and therefore no other information is needed.

In your example, the css selector `#input[placeholder=...']` selector would select an element with an `id` equal to `input`.
If you intended selecting an `input` tag with a specific `placeholder` you should omit the `#`.

Comment: doberkofler,
Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: @GwezaKwer Please do not forget to accept my answer if helpful